# On subgroups of a finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group such that $G$ is of odd order or 
decomposition of the sylow 2-subgroups of $G$ there is at least two
cyclic direct factors of maximal order. Then prove or disprove that 
for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ there exists an automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ such that 
$H=\{g\in G| \alpha(g)=g\}$.

I think this is true.

Thank you

Comment: @DerekHolt: Please guide me.

Comment: In fact, for a cyclic $2$-group $G$, the only subgroup $H$ for which the conclusion is false is the trivial subgroup, because all automorphisms must fix the unique element of order $2$. Using that, I think you can reduce to $G = C_1 \times \cdots C_k$ (where $k \ge 2$) for cyclic $2$-groups, with $|C_i| \le |C_{i+1}|$, $|C_{k-1}|=|C_k|$, and $H$ is a possibly trivial subgroup of $C_k$. It is not hard to find $\alpha$ that fixes nothing in $C_i$ for $i<k-1$, so this effectively reduces it to the case $k=2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you for your expalaintion. Only i dont know the first line in the first your comment: We know that every subgroup of $G_{1}\times G_{2}$ is a subproduct if and only if $(|G_{1}|,|G_{2}|)=1$. But here there is not this property. For example if $G=\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $H=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. Please explain more about the first line in the first comment.

Comment: You keep mixing up additive and multiplicative notation! I will use additive. In your example, write $G = C_1 \oplus C_2$ with $C_1 = \langle (1,0) \rangle$, $C_2=\langle (1,1) \rangle$. Then $H \le C_2$. It follows from the basic theory of subgroups of free abelian groups that you can always do that. Without using that, I don't see any way of attacking the problem.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Ok. Thank you very much for explainations. Do there exists a book that i study this property in free abelian groups?
Your informations is extraordinary in all subjects of group theory. your comments or answers are very nice. I like study hard and increase very very much my inoformation in subject group theory inparticular "Automorphisms". Please introduce some good books.